# Powershell caret "^" not showing in string

Tags: string, internet-explorer, powershell

I am having difficulty passing a caret as part of a string in a password

```
function OpenIE([string]$url, [string]$p)
{
    $wshell = New-Object -com WScript.Shell
    $wshell.Run("iexplore.exe $url")
    Start-Sleep 5
    $wshell.sendkeys("fake`$pass`^word")
}
```

When I run this it enters the following:
fake$passord

How would I get the password to input correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) uses the `^` charter to represent the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key was pressed, so to the receiving program it looked like you did `fake$pass(ctrl+w)ord`. You must escape it by wrapping it in `{^}`, the curly braces will not show up in the final text.

```
function OpenIE([string]$url, [string]$p)
{
    $wshell = New-Object -com WScript.Shell
    $wshell.Run("iexplore.exe $url")
    Start-Sleep 5
    $wshell.sendkeys("fake`$pass`{^}word")
}
```